# Passing sudo flags into makefile

Tags: python, bash, proxy, makefile, sudo

I am currently located behind a proxy.  Sitting in the land of bash, I have my HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY set as environment variables set to the proxy.  When I want to install something under sudo, like pip, I have to use the -E flag with sudo to get the install to work:

```
sudo -E pip install 'selenium>=2.40.0'
```

That is fine and works.

However I have some across a Makefile that calls sudo pip install.  Even if I call make with the -E flag

```
sudo -E make install
```

The -E flag from sudo is no picked up in the Makefile when the makefile tries to do an installation from pip (that I am using)

Is is possible for a Makefile to pick up the flags used when calling the sudo command?

Comment: No. You'll have to edit the Makefile if `-E` is really required.

Comment: Dammit, I was afraid of that, fair enough, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

before calling any makefile that has 'sudo pip install', you could set an alias for sudo .  Ex:

```
alias sudo='sudo -E'
make install
```

To remove the alias for the rest of the process;

```
unalias sudo
```

(you can, of course, skip the unalias if you want it to persist for the duration of the process)